# MySql Query - How to delete Merchant account and his related products in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a website which is having two tables: 1- username 2- products.

**fields of merchant**

- merchant_ID
- full_name
- username
- email
- password

**fields of products table**

- product_title
- pro_description
- merchant_ID
- pro_price
- pro_discount

In the username table I am storing the merchant information and in the product table I am storing the merchants uploaded products.

Please make a query for removing a merchants account (from the table username) and his uploaded products (from the products table) at once.

Comment: sounds like homework...

Comment: Do your database tables have foreign key constraints? If so, delete cascade is pretty nifty

Comment: Did any of the two answers help you? If yes, press the green symbol. If no, and if you found a solution, you can still answer your question youself, this can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I approve with @Tilman Hausherr, sounds like homework and one more thing, you want SQL query so why don't you tag it with 'sql' tag?

And the answer is, I'm not pretty sure if it's good to do that, because we don't know, how it all works.
So maybe there is more effective way to do that **separately**.
But you could try **Multiple Statements in PHP 5** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php I haven't tried it, as we said, we need to know, how it works.

Comment: Multiple statements is less important than multiple queries within a single ACID transaction, so that you can rollback if any part of the deletion fails

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have foreign key constraints. it is easy to delete by setting **CASCADE**, but you can also delete by using **INNER JOIN** from both table like this way, change conditions as per your requirements.

```
DELETE m.*,p.* FROM merchant m
INNER JOIN product p ON m.merchant_id = p.merchant_id
```

**Simplest way**: You should use FOREIGN KEYS With ON DELETE CASCADE.